# How do I get NSolve to work with hyperbolic functions?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

This is a rather simple numerical solution, but it simply doesn't work. Does anybody have a solution?

```
NSolve[x - Sinh[x] - 1 == 0, x]
```

> NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available
>   to NSolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSolve[x - Sinh[x] - 1 == 0, x, Reals]
(*
 {{x -> -1.72912}}
*)
```

Comment: That is strange, since the first thing I tried is this: `Assuming[Element[x, Reals], NSolve[x - Sinh[x] - 1 == 0, x]]` and it did not work ! I see from help now that NSolve takes Reals as second argument. But this is not very consistent with how other functions work, by using Assuming.

Comment: @Nasser I don't think the assumption is taking effect on the NSolve "Block[]"